# mongoose debug do not format ObjectId in aggregate method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to enable debug in mongoose

```
mongoose.set('debug', true)
```

And then every query will show in the console with colors like that

```
users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("61babeae3e6086973a71f0d1")})
```

But when I use `aggregate` method, the result like that

```
users.aggregate([ { '$match': {_id: {$in: [61babeae3e6086973a71f0d1]}}])
```

How can I format ObjectId?
Same issue with Date value

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose automatically uses string values as ObjectId in its find, update, delete, and other regular queries. However, this is not the case for aggregation pipeline queries. So, you have to manually cast the string ObjectIds as:

```
users.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            _id: {
                $in:  [mongoose.Types.ObjectId('61babeae3e6086973a71f0d1')]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

This is described in issue #1399 here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1399

For Date values, use them in $match stage as:

```
 users.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            createdAt: {
                $gte: new Date('2021-08-06T07:50:29.279')
            }
        }
    }
])
```